# Adding invisible recaptcha v2 to jquery ajax add to cart form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, recaptcha

So on our Miva 9 website I would like to add the inivisible recaptcha v2 to our product pages for the add to cart form.

Here is what i have in the head tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var onSubmit = function(response) {
            document.getElementById("js-purchase-product").submit(); // send response to your backend service
        };
    </script>
```

This is the form html:

```
        <form method="post" action="&mvte:urls:BASK:auto;" name="add" id="js-purchase-product">
            <input type="hidden" name="Old_Screen" value="&mvte:global:Screen;" />
            <input type="hidden" name="Old_Search" value="&mvte:global:Search;" />
            <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="ADPR" />
            <input type="hidden" name="Product_Code" value="&mvte:product:code;" />
            <input type="hidden" name="Category_Code" value="&mvte:global:category_code;" />
            <input type="hidden" name="Offset" value="&mvte:global:Offset;" />
            <input type="hidden" name="AllOffset" value="&mvte:global:AllOffset;" />
            <input type="hidden" name="CatListingOffset" value="&mvte:global:CatListingOffset;" />
            <input type="hidden" name="RelatedOffset" value="&mvte:global:RelatedOffset;" />
            <input type="hidden" name="SearchOffset" value="&mvte:global:SearchOffset;" />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column whole">
                    <div id="js-purchase-message" class="message message-warning purchase-message"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- form fields -->
                <div id="js-product-attributes" class="column whole product-attributes mtp1-25 mbm1-25">
                    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
                        <script src="&mvte:global:theme_path;/js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                    <mvt:item name="product_attributes" param="product:id" />
                </div>
                <!-- end form fields -->

                <div class="column whole np">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE-KEY-XXXXXXXXXXXX" data-callback="onSubmit" data-badge="inline" data-size="invisible"></div>
                    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
                </div>
                <!-- end invisible recaptcha -->

            </div>
            <div class="row corners add-to-cart-wrap bg-lt-gray">
                <div class="column whole align-center">
                    <div class="bold">Price Subtotal<br /><span class="small normal">(with options added)</span></div>
                    <div id="js-price-value" class="h3 charcoal nm" data-base-price="&mvt:product:price;">&mvt:product:formatted_price;</div>
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="column whole small-half medium-whole large-two-fifths x-large-three-tenths print-hide">
                    <div class="row quantity-wrap align-center">
                        <div class="column whole np">
                            <span id="js-decrease-quantity" class="bg-gray corners-left decrease-quantity" unselectable="on"
                             data-rt-icon="&#xf068;"></span>
                            <input type="tel" name="Quantity" value="1" id="l-quantity" class="align-center" style="font-size:1rem" />
                            <span id="js-increase-quantity" class="bg-gray corners-right increase-quantity" unselectable="on"
                             data-rt-icon="&#xf067;"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column whole small-half medium-whole large-three-fifths x-large-seven-tenths print-hide">
                    <div class="breaker small-all-hidden medium-all-shown large-all-hidden"></div>
                    <span onclick="document.forms.add.action = '&mvtj:urls:BASK:auto;'; document.forms.add.elements.Action.value = 'ADPR';">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" data-value="Add to Cart" id="js-add-to-cart" class="button button-block corners uppercase add-to-cart black bg-sky bold" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and here is was is in our scripts file for the AJAX Add to Cart:

```
        // ---- AJAX Add To Cart ---- //

        function addToCart () {

            $('#js-add-to-cart').on('click', function (e) {

                var purchaseForm = $('#js-purchase-product');

                // Check the form is not currently submitting

                if (purchaseForm.data('formstatus') !== 'submitting') {

                    // Set up variables

                    var form = purchaseForm,

                        formData = form.serialize(),

                        randomNo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000), // IE Hack: Creating random number to refresh ajax call

                        formUrl = form.attr('action'),

                        formMethod = form.attr('method'),

                        responseMessage = $('#js-purchase-message'),

                        miniBasket = $('#js-mini-basket-container'),

                        processingImage = $('#js-processing-purchase'),

                        purchaseButton = $(this),

                        purchaseButtonText = purchaseButton.val();



                    if (/\?/.test(formUrl)) {

                        formUrl = formUrl + '&v=' + randomNo;

                    }

                    else {

                        formUrl = formUrl + '?v=' + randomNo;

                    };



                    // Add status data to form

                    form.data('formstatus', 'submitting');



                    // Show processing message

                    processingImage.show();

                    purchaseButton.toggleDisabled().val('Processing...');

                    responseMessage.html('').hide();



                    // Send data to server for validation

                    $.ajax({

                        url: formUrl,

                        type: formMethod,

                        data: formData,

                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                            if (data.search(/id="js-BASK"/i) != -1) {

                                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 250);

                                var responseMiniBasket = $(data).find('#js-mini-basket-container'),

                                    miniBasketCount = responseMiniBasket.contents()[1].getAttribute('data-itemcount'),

                                    miniBasketSubtotal = ' ' + responseMiniBasket.contents()[1].getAttribute('data-subtotal'),

                                    miniBasketLinkCount = $('#js-mini-basket-count, #js-mobile-basket-button .notification'),

                                    miniBasketLinkSubtotal = $('#js-mini-basket-subtotal');



                                miniBasketLinkCount.text(miniBasketCount); // Update basket quantity (display only)

                                miniBasketLinkSubtotal.text(miniBasketSubtotal); // Update basket subtotal (display only)



                                miniBasket.html(responseMiniBasket.contents()).addClass('open');
                                $('.mini-basket-table-wrap').scrollTop($('.mini-basket-table-wrap')[0].scrollHeight);

                                setTimeout(function () {

                                    miniBasket.removeClass('open');

                                    if ( $( "#family-tree" ).length ) {

                                        $(document).ready(function(){
                                            var url = "/family-tree-hearts-discs.html";
                                            $(location).attr('href',url);
                                        });

                                    };

                                    if ( $( "#wholesale-family-tree" ).length ) {

                                        $(document).ready(function(){
                                            var url = "/wholesale-family-tree-hearts-discs.html";
                                            $(location).attr('href',url);
                                        });

                                    };

                                }, 3000);

                                // Re-Initialize Attribute Machine (if it is active)

                                if (typeof attrMachCall !== 'undefined') {

                                    attrMachCall.Initialize();

                                };

                            }

                            else if(data.search(/id="js-PATR"/i) != -1) {

                                var missingAttrs = [];

                                form.find('.required').each(function () {

                                    missingAttrs.push(' ' + $(this).attr('title'));

                                });

                                responseMessage.html('All <em class="red">Required</em> options have not been selected.<br />Please review the following options: <span class="red">' + missingAttrs + '</span>.').fadeIn();
                                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($('#js-purchase-message').offset().top - 100)},500);

                            }

                            else if(data.search(/id="js-PLMT"/i) != -1) {

                                responseMessage.html('We do not have enough of the Size/Color you have selected.<br />Please adjust your quantity.').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($('#js-inventory-message').offset().top - 100)},500);

                            }

                            else if(data.search(/id="js-POUT"/i) != -1) {

                                responseMessage.html('The Size/Color you have selected is out of stock.<br />Please review your options or check back later.').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($('#js-inventory-message').offset().top - 100)},500); 

                            }

                            else {

                                responseMessage.html('Please review options.').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($('#js-purchase-message').offset().top - 100)},500);

                            };



                            // Hide processing message and reset formstatus

                            processingImage.hide();

                            purchaseButton.toggleDisabled().val(purchaseButtonText);

                            form.data('formstatus', 'idle');

                        },

                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        }

                    });

                };

                // Prevent form from submitting

                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.preventDefault();

            });

        };

        var addToCart = new addToCart;
```

The trouble I am having is:

Where do I add grecaptcha.execute();?

I want to keep the functionality of the ajax add to cart and form validation.

When a user adds to the cart the mini basket slides open and the product is added. They are not taken off the product page.

And if they do not select a or fill out a required form field, the page scrolls up and an error message is displayed and they stay on the product page.

Here is a link to a product page for reference: https://www.loveisarose.com/ILYR11.html

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please don't use the jQuery Validate tag unless you're using this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: sorry about that @Sparky